# week-dates in R

Tags: r, date

In R, how do I convert the string `1/2010` (week 1 of 2010) into a `Date` or `POSIXct` (or `POSIXlt`) object?

I tried

```
as.Date('1/2010', "%W/%Y")
[1] "2010-06-29"
```

I also tried

```
strptime('1/2010', "%W/%Y")
[1] "2010-06-29 BRT"
```

But these are clearly not what I want.

In the end, I guess doesn't really matter which exact is picked, so long as I can correctly re-convert this to "weeks since origin".

Comment: A week has 7 different dates in it. Which one should be picked?

Comment: thanks @DavidArenburg, I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Perhaps `paste` an arbitrary weekday (`%u`) to your week-year?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing Henrik. `strptime(paste0('0/', '1/2010'), '%w/%W/%Y')` will give you the Sunday for any week that is passed to the second part of the `paste0` function.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(splitstackshape)

date <- c("1/2013","3/2013")
date = data.frame(date)

df = data.frame(cSplit(date,"date","/"))

colnames(df) = c("week", "year")

df$date = as.Date(paste(df$year, df$week, 1, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")
```

Comment: @djas Hope it is what you need!

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.